# Can't query my bigQuery Error Unrecognized name

Tags: google-bigquery

I need some help.

I have this script to send pubsub messages to my topic:

```
const topicName = "---";
const data = JSON.stringify({
  customerToken: "teste",
  fbclid: "Icanchangethat",
  fbc: "Itworks",
  fbp: "thisismydata",
  firstHitTS: "2021-01-12",
  consentFB: true,
});

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const { PubSub } = require("@google-cloud/pubsub");

// Creates a client; cache this for further use
const pubSubClient = new PubSub();

async function publishMessageWithCustomAttributes() {
  // Publishes the message as a string, e.g. "Hello, world!" or JSON.stringify(someObject)
  const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);

  // Add two custom attributes, origin and username, to the message
  const customAttributes = {};

  const messageId = await pubSubClient
    .topic(topicName)
    .publish(dataBuffer, customAttributes);
  console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
  console.log(customAttributes);
}

publishMessageWithCustomAttributes().catch(console.error);
```

As you can see I send data in my message (customerToken,fbclid..etc)

With this cloud func:

```
const { BigQuery } = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");
const bigquery = new BigQuery();

exports.insertBigQuery = async (message, context) => {
  // Decode base64 the PubSub message
  let logData = Buffer.from(message.data, "base64").toString();
  // Convert it in JSON
  let logMessage = JSON.parse(logData);

  const query = createQuery(logMessage);

  const options = {
    query: query,
    location: "US",
  };

  const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
  console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);

  // Only wait the end of the job. Theere is no row as answer, it's only an insert
  await job.getQueryResults();
};

function createQuery(logMessage) {
  return `INSERT INTO MYTABLE(customerToken, fbclid, fbc, fbp, firstHitTS, consentFB)
          VALUES (`+logMessage.customerToken+`,`+ logMessage.fbclid+`,`+ logMessage.fbc+`,`+ logMessage.fbp+`,`+logMessage.firstHitTS+`,`+logMessage.consentFB+`)`;
}
```

I need to query the data I've receive from the message into my bigQuery, every thing seems to be working but I keep receiving  `Error: Unrecognized name: teste at [2:19]` test is the value for customerToken.

I went through the other posts but I could not find an answer that works for me, anyone can help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should check the formed query returned by createQuery(logMessage), if you do, you'll find the `VALUES` clause is like `VALUES(teste, ...` , I guess you want to quote it like `VALUES('teste', ...`

Comment: thank you @YunZhang that was the problem!